# How to display the full image in v-parallax?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I choose vuetify for my project. Great frontend framework. Question is, how to make v-parallax to display the full image without croped. Some code shows below, and the full code is hosted in code pen.

```
<v-parallax
      src="https://blog-images-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/media/private/carlos-muza-84523_u62x84y.jpg"
      height="600"
      jumbotron
></v-parallax>
```

https://codepen.io/tonywangcn/pen/WdENYQ

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set the img's `height="100%"` to solve that.

https://codepen.io/Shiv_UIDeveloper/pen/RxZNEa

Answer (score 5):

The problem here isn't the height, it's the `transform` property which skews the width of the image. Unfortunately there's no prop in Vuetify's parallax component for adjusting the width of the image so all you can do is adjust the image dimensions or overwrite the transform property:

```
.v-parallax__image {
  transform: none !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just use `height="100%"` to solve that

You can see [it working here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZvwNq)

Note that you need the parent containers to also have 100% height for this to work

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Sadly it's not working. Just displayed the lower half of the full image.  Full image here https://blog-images-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/media/private/carlos-muza-84523_u62x84y.jpg

Comment: @TonyWang Works fine in my codepen. Add more elements so the page is bigger, you'll see it

Comment: yeah, drag the chrome higher enough... But is there any better solution. Supposing user just have a fixed height and width, and how to disply the large image in a small container?

Comment: @TonyWang Then define a smaller container and put the parallax in it, give that container a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar problem with this component. I was trying to swap in the image as part of a lazy-load, but the component did not accurately render it. Instead, the component cropped the image severely. Setting the :src="" attribute to the correct image immediately, and choosing an image that is taller than wide worked.

Answer (score 0):

try insert v-parallax inside v-layout and v-flex.

```
<v-layout row wrap>
  <v-flex xs12 sm12>
    <v-parallax :src="getImageUrl('art01.jpg')">
      <v-layout column align-center justify-center>
        <h1>title</h1>
      </v-layout>
    </v-parallax>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    getImageUrl(img) {
      return require(`~/assets/user/images/${img}`) 
    }
  },
}
</script>
```